# Custom shortcut not working

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, system-monitor

I've tried setting a custom shortcut for gnome-system-monitor on SHIFT+CTRL+ESCAPE because that's what I use on windows and I want it on ubuntu too. But it doesn't work. I tried setting the command, from settings-keyboard-shortcuts, as simply "gnome-system-monitor", then as "/usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor", and then tried setting it from compiz manager under commands. Nothing worked. My other shortcuts work (for example I have a shortcut of alt+win+f4 for poweroff).
I have ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

[image: photo of shortcut 1]

[image: photo of shortcut 2]

Comment: Was this done from `system settings --> keyboard --> shortcuts`?

Comment: Yeah.. I'll edit it to be more plain

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the shortcut editor?

Comment: please lets have a screen shot of the command you entered

Comment: did you try deleting the shortcut and creating it again? this method worked for me.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the output of command `/usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor` in terminal? That might help in understanding the source of problem.

Comment: tried deleting, didn't work.. also nothing to post.. when I enter the command the system monitor starts normally and closes normally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Something that has to do with ESC probably. I'm not sure but it is possible that can't be used in a shortcut. Or there is a problem with this specific combo, though I couldn't find any other shortcut that uses it which would be a problem.

I changed it to SHIFT+CTRL+HOME and it now works!

Comment: SHIFT+CTRL+ESC works perfectly for me on Mint.